# Free library to read PDF files

Tags: vba, pdf, com

Is there a free way to read PDF files through VBA to extract basic text content? I need to automate a weekly data acquisition process at my company where data is contained in PDF files (which are updated weekly by the data provider). Also, is there a reference I can look into to understand the file structure (DOM?) of a PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe's PDF reference is online here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html

I'm not sure about the best way to read PDFs from VBA directly, but if you can call an external Java or C# program, then I would recommend using [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/) for [basic text extraction](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/27).

EDIT: I should maybe mention that Adobe's PDF reference is an 800 page beast. I found that it's good for looking up answers to particular questions (eg, storing widths of embedded truetype fonts), but it may not be a good place to start. For that, reading through the [iText book](http://itextpdf.com/book/) helped me to get started on the format.

Comment: it's probably worth to mention that iText/iTextSharp aren't free (unless used in open source project).

Answer (score 1):

The IText book contains lots of worked examples for general PDF tasks and lots of background info to help you understand PDF files. It more than pays for itself very quickly!